# Generete unique random number on large number range

Tags: math, random

what i ask about is if exist a way to generate unique random numbers without helper structures.

I mean if already exist some mathematics functions (or algorithms) that natively generate random numbers only at once on a field (i would not try to write some kind of hash function specific for this problem).

This because i would  generate a lot of unique numbers (integer) choosen between 0 and 10.000.000.000 (about 60% of the field), so a random repetition is not so improbable and store previously generated number in a structure for a subsequent lookup (even if well optimized, like bit arrays) could be too expensive (spatially and temporally).

P.S.

(Note that when i write random i really mean pseudo random)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to ensure uniqueness then do not use a hash function, but instead use an encryption function to encrypt the numbers 0, 1, 2, 3 ...  Since encryption is reversible then every number (up to the block size) is uniquely encrypted and will produce a unique result.

You can either write a simple Feistel cypher with a convenient block size or else use the Hasty Pudding cypher, which allows a large range of block sizes.  Whenever an input number generates too large an output, then just go to the next input number.

Changing the key of the cypher will generate a different series of output numbers.  the same series of numbers can be regenerated whenever needed by remembering the key and starting again with 0, 1, 2 ...  There is no need to store the entire sequence.  As you say, the sequence is pseudo-random and so can be regenerated easily if you know the key.

Comment: nice solution.
Meanwhile i've also found this link http://preshing.com/20121224/how-to-generate-a-sequence-of-unique-random-integers/ that's about quadratic resides.
Do you think that the solution in the link could be faster than use encryption? Could also provide an accpetable randomness compared with your solution? 
I've no mentioned it before but speed of generation is one crucial point.

Comment: You can never tell about speed in advance.  Write a solution and see if it is fast enough.  Only try a second idea if the first idea is too slow.  Hasty Pudding will be slower than a simple (hence insecure) Feistel cypher with only four rounds (even more insecure).

Comment: I've tested this solution using Java AES CTR (to achieve one byte resolution) and for small sets (8bit) it's completly no random.
With medium sets results are better, but encrypt still be a monotone function.

Comment: I've tested this solution using Java AES CTR (to achieve one byte resolution) and for small sets (8bit) it's completly no random.
With medium sets results are better, but encrypt still be a monotone function.Implementation http://pastebin.com/3Pz3qXf0 Result 8b http://pastebin.com/rEcBn9Y1 Result 16b http://pastebin.com/Kvu5J4Dv  (sorry but i can't edit my previous truncated comment)

Comment: CTR mode is probably not a good choice.  Better to use ECB since you are more interested in the permutation properties of the cypher than the cryptographic properties.  Each number is a block, encrypted using ECB to a different unique block.

Comment: With CTR i could easily generate a space about n byte even with n very small (eg: one or two). With EBC blocks (they are about 16 byte space) obtain only n (with n small) bytes of the block used become a challange.
Could you explain to me how you generate (pratically) a 16bit (2 byte) space using a  normal AES in ECB mode (that use about 16 byte per block)? (and without any truncation in the result eg: taking only first two byte of cipher text, because this would break the uniqueness of result) because i do not see any way. Need i to use a stream cipher instead?

Comment: If you want 16 bits then use a 16 bit block cypher.  It is easy enough to write a simple [Feistel cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feistel_cipher) with 16 bit blocks and only four rounds.  It will be insecure, but security does not seem to be a requirement for what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pseudo-random numbers, you could try so-called quasi-random numbers, which are more accurately called low-discrepancy sequences. [1]

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-discrepancy_sequence

Comment: sorry but i do not know them (i've read wikipedia, and few other sources, but i still have not idea about how use them).
Could you make me an example that explain how could i generate a garanted unique number on a field of n bits with these technique?